# Doing more than asked for?

Tags: undergraduate

In a course I am not doing as well as I wanted and I asked the professor for extra credit but he refused saying his goal is to see how well we do compared to our peers. Giving extra credit to one student will make his grade not directly comparable to the others.

On the other hand I am absolutely determined to ace this course no matter what and make up for my mistakes on the exercises.

In this course we have a huge project upcoming. We are asked to design a user interface (in paper). The implementation is out of the scope of the course.

So, I was thinking, maybe I should implement it and hope the professor will give me extra credit? It won't take me much time.

Comment: Sounds like your prof has already answered quite clearly.

Comment: If the project is important to your overall grade, put a lot of effort into doing **exactly** what was asked for, no more and no less.

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan Sure, but this way I can't make up for my past mistakes.

Comment: @NET_GUY Why do you assume you can make up for past mistakes? We all make mistakes, but they do have consequences.

Comment: Generally, at least here, any way to give students extra credit would have to be offered to ALL students of the course. So, a teacher could offer an extra assignment where they can earn extra credit (but if they don't do it, the credit they could have earned is not counted to what would be 100% of the credit for the course). But you just cannot (legally) give a student extra credit, especially not for something you did not ask them to do.

Comment: The importance of @patriciashanahan 's remark cannot be overestimated. Growing up as a professional means, among other things, being able to understand what you are asked to do.

Comment: To those voting to close: What is it about this question that prevents it from applying to graduate students? As a graduate student, I took courses that involved both coursework and a final project.

Comment: I see everyone's point here. IMHO the question fits the site. Maybe I sound way too aggressive and some people don't like this, but still pretty valid question.

Comment: I disagree with the close votes and voted to reopen: this is certainly a question that could be generalized to graduate education.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> maybe I should implement it and hope the professor will give me extra credit?

Probably it won't work, if he has already explicitly said no. But we don't know your prof and don't have the magic power of prophecy. (I think it's unlocked at 3.000.000 reputation.)

Comment: So, Jon Skeet should get this power soon...

Comment: If you waste your time on something that hasn't been asked for instead of investing it into what is being asked for, you won't get extra credit.

Comment: @Captain Emacs Whoaa

Answer (score 5):

It seems that your professor has made it quite clear, and with solid reasons, as to why the extra credit is very unlikely to happen at all.

As such, it becomes imperative to complete the task according to the task instructions - as this is how the professor will be assessing it.

Having said all that, by all means complete the implementation -if time allows - at the very least, this would be a good self learning avenue - even show the professor, but please do not continually ask for extra credit - if he wishes to award it, he will offer it.